# How can implement an editor in a webpage which can highlight LaTeX and AMS keyword?

Tags: javascript

The keyword can be highlighted when I use Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010,
How can implement an editor in a webpage which can highlight LaTeX and AMS keyword? Thanks!

Comment: You mean a syntax highlighter?

Comment: Yes, I hope to mean a syntax highlighter after I typed

Comment: Thanks! What I need is a syntax highlighter when I is editing text.

Answer (score 0):

> Quote:
>
> Yes, I hope to mean a syntax highlighter after I typed -- Paul

You can use a `jQuery` syntax highlighter plugin (you'll find many of them by a simple search.) In many of them you can define keywords and maybe some rules (usually as regular expressions) for `LaTeX` and `AMS` grammar.

If you want to do it manually you can create a parser either manually or by using a `Javascript` parser generator like [this](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online).

Basically you should define some rules to distinguish lexems (tokens) types and wrap the things that should be shown in different color or format in `<span>` tags for example, with a css class:

```
$('lexemSelector').wrap('<span />').addClass(lexemType);
```

---

> Quote:
>
> How can implement an editor in a webpage...

If you want to create an online `LaTeX` and `AMS` editor with on the fly syntax highlighting you may want to take a look at [`codemirror`](http://codemirror.net/). It already [supports `LaTeX`](http://codemirror.net/mode/stex/index.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! What I need is a syntax highlighter keyword when webpage is in edit text mode